# How to convert pandas dataframe to json

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have json that looks like this:

```
{
    "response": {
        "docs": [{
                "region_s" : "North America",
                "country_s": "Panama",
                "ArticleHeading_s": "The expected vaccination process begins in Chiriquí",
                "ArticleDate_s": "Fri Jun 18 17:29:07 UTC 2021",
                "refined_summary_t": "Este jueves 13 de mayo la Operación PanavaC-19 inició el proceso de inmunización a los adultos mayores de 60 ",
                "id": "http://www.minsa.gob.pa/noticia/arranca-esperado-proceso-de-vacunacion-en-chiriqui",
                "source_type_s": "Guidances/Regulations",
                "curation_date_t":"12 Jun 2021 to 28 Jun 2021"
            },
            {
                "region_s" : "North America",
                "country_s": "US",
                "ArticleHeading_s": "Emergency Use Authorization for Vaccines to Prevent COVID-19: Guidance for Industry",
                "ArticleDate_s": "Fri Jun 15 17:29:07 UTC 2021",
                "refined_summary_t": "<ol><li> first list</li> Second</li></ol>",
                "id": "http://www.minsa.gob.pa/noticia/arranca-esperado-proceso-de-vacunacion-en-chiriqui",
                "source_type_s": "Press Releases/News",
                "curation_date_t":"12 Jun 2021 to 18 Jun 2021"
            }]
```

I convert it into pandas frame append some data and then need to convert it back to json. My final df looks something like this
[image]

I want to be able to convert it back to json. This is what the code looks like

```
out = {"response" : {"docs" : {[]} }}
out["response"]["docs"].append(df.to_json(orient='records')[1:-1].replace("'{","{" ))
print(out)
with open('file_name.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(out)
```

Unfortunately, it gives out an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 42, in <module>
    out = {"response" : {"docs" : {[]} }}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do:

```py
docs = df.to_dict('records')
out = { 
   "response":{
      "docs":docs,
   },
}
```

and the dump the out dictionary to json file

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
out = {"response" : {"docs" : {[]} }}
```

Where `docs` should be a `list`, you declared it as a `set` with a mutable type element, which is not legal. I'm assuming you meant:

```
out = {"response" : {"docs" : [] }}
```